# Should I enable ubuntu updates in software-properties-gtk?

Tags: updates, applications, ubuntu

I'm using relase loki and I have installed software-properties-gtk I see that there is an option to enable updates and I was wondering if I should enable them on elementary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not as elementary is based on ubuntu lts. if you upgrade the ubuntu side you might break your elementary. I might try it on another drive, just to see what happens...:-)